# Spinner dropdown list to show below the spinner widget

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I need the list of the `spinner` to show below its widget.

I tried `android:dropDownVerticalOffset="15dp"` that works on my OP6 phone, but doesn't work on Samsung phone. And `id:overlapAnchor="false"` doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spStates"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_expandable_parent_item"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="65dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_headline"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_headline"
                />
```

How I want (OP6):
[image]

How it's showing (Samsung):
[image]

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for responsive UI

Comment: the same problem.

Comment: android:dropDownVerticalOffset="65dp" seems to have problem on some devices. As can be see, Samsung doesn't change the gap even for 1 dp. The attribute just doesn't work!

Comment: Hi, is the component with id tv_headline a layout, within which the spinner resides?

Comment: @ACR yes, tv_headline is a TextView. Since I couldn't customise the head of spinner, I had to put behind this TextView. Spinner is opened programatically.

Comment: ok. Then I guess, it may be the constraints that may be causing the issue. The constraints given are top to the top of textview and bottom to the bottom of textview and spinner height is 0dp.

Comment: What do you mean by pointing to the constraints? I want the spinner to be as high as TextView is.

Comment: Hi, Can you paste the code for the layout surrounding the spinner?